# Resolve dependency Injection for abstract class in .Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using .net Core 2.0.

I have one MemberInfo class which will inherit the Member Abstract class. Need to resolve the Dependency in StartUp.cs file.

```
public class MemberInfo : Member
{
    public MemberInfo()
    {

    }
}
public abstract class Member: IMemberDetails
{
    public DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;;
}
```

In startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {   
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
services.AddScoped<IMemberDetails, Member>();
services.AddScoped<Member, MemberInfo >();
}
```

I am getting exception message as

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MemberIfo' while attempting to activate 'ProcessData'`.

Comment: Show the `ProcessData` class (include the constructor  and its arguments)

Answer (score 5):

Your ProcessData-Class can't find a MemberInfo because you added MemberInfo as representation for the Member-class. If you want to access the type MemberInfo directly you need to do `services.AddScoped<MemberInfo, MemberInfo >();` or shorter `services.AddScoped<MemberInfo>();`.

If you only need the abstract definition you should request the abstract class `Member`, not the concrete implementation `MemberInfo` in your ProcessData-class. To make the differentiation between definition and implementation more clear you might want to add an interface as was pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57200125/3085985).

If you want to have both types available pointing to the same implementation but don't want to have multiple instances in the same scope you can do something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<MemberInfo>();
services.AddScoped<Member>((serviceProvider) => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MemberInfo>());
```

Answer (score 1):

First one you have a syntax error you injecting `MemberInfo` but the log showing `MemberIfo` that might be the problem, also it is better to do injections with `Interface` maybe your `Member` class in `services.AddScoped<Member, MemberInfo >();` it Interface it is hard to tell from here.

Also `DependencyInjections` work only in `Controller` class. Your class doe's not inherit from a Controller class and do not use the key word "Controller".
Your code:

```
public class MemberInfo : Member
{
    public MemberInfo()
    {

    }
}
public abstract class Member: IMemberDetails
{
    public DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;;
}
```

How dependency injection actually should look:

```
public class MemberInfoController : Controller
{
      IMemberDetails details;
      public MemberInfo(IMemberDetails det)
      {
          details = det;
      }
}
```

```
// further code
```

**Also a few notes**

If you wont to use injected dependency outside of controller you can just pass it with a function.

Like this

```
// Here was DependencyInjection

public IActionResult res()
{
   MyClass class = new MyClass();
   class.SomeFunc(details);
}
```